GooglePlacesAutocomplete not working in expo app, throws "Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported"
I am trying to use GooglePlacesAutocomplete in my expo app. I installed it in my expo app with the following command:
npx expo install react-native-google-places-autocomplete

And I am using it on a screen as such:
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

const CreateProfile = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}>
            <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                placeholder="Enter address"
                minLength={2} 
                fetchDetails={true} address
                onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                    
                    console.log(data, details);
                   
                }}
                query={{
                    key: "<apiKey>",
                    language: 'en', 
                    components: 'country:us',
                }}
                styles={{
                    textInputContainer: {
                        width: '100%',
                    },
                    textInput: {
                        height: 50,
                        color: '#5d5d5d',
                        fontSize: 16,
                    },
                    predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                        color: '#1faadb',
                    },
                }}
                nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
                debounce={200}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export default CreateProfile;


When I do this I keep getting the following error:
 ERROR  Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported

This error is located at:
    in GooglePlacesAutocomplete (created by CreateProfile)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CreateProfile)
    in CreateProfile (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in CardSheet (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Animated(View))
    in Animated(View) (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Animated(View))
    in Animated(View) (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
    in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by TabsAuthNavigator)
    in TabsAuthNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in CardSheet (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Animated(View))
    in Animated(View) (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Animated(View))
    in Animated(View) (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
    in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App
    in Unknown (created by Route((tabs)/index))
    in Suspense (created by Route((tabs)/index))
    in Route (created by Route((tabs)/index))
    in Route((tabs)/index) (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by QualifiedSlot)
    in QualifiedSlot (created by DefaultNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by QualifiedNavigator)
    in QualifiedNavigator (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by DefaultNavigator)
    in RNCSafeAreaView
    in Unknown (created by DefaultNavigator)
    in DefaultNavigator
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Suspense (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in Route() (created by ContextNavigator)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by wrapper)
    in wrapper (created by ContextNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay (created by withDevTools(ErrorOverlay))
    in withDevTools(ErrorOverlay)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes


This is the version I have installed:
"react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.7",

And I am trying to run it on an Android Emulator that's running Android 15
I tried installing npx expo install @types/react-native-get-random-values and importing it at the top of my index.tsx file, but that resulted in the error "Render Error: Native module not found"

Any luck? I am getting the same error

Use this version:
npm i react-native-google-places-autocomplete@2.5.6

@zaibatsu Yeah I had to rebuild my app and then also make my API key unrestricted and then it started working. My solution was just importing the react-native-get-random-values package at the top of index.tsx and then rebuilding. It didn't work until I rebuilt my app and reinstalled it in my emulator

Just install this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-random-values and then import it on the entry route of your project; top layout if using expo router, or app.js/tsx or index.js/tsx:
import 'react-native-get-random-values';


As I stated in the last paragraph, I tried that and then I get the error "Render Error: Native module not found"

Are you using expo go or development build?¿

I am using development build. I had to rebuild the app and then it worked. It did not work until I rebuilt the app and reinstalled it into my emulator.

@NicolásMartínezCara this works for me
